# problem uploading and dragging angular project files to github

Tags: angular, github

hey whenever I try to upload and drag my angular project to github repository not all the files are uploaded, for example empty css files. is there any faster way to copy the files to my repo? I don't need to run my app on github but only see the full code over there(not the dist)

thanks a lot

Comment: put all of your required CSS files in the asset folder because in GitHub you can't upload ng-module

Comment: But some css files does uploaded. Only the empty one doesn’t